# conditional loop in jquery selector

Tags: jquery

How can I select the first 3 div elements in the following example using jquery?

I want to select the div elements with status = 0 until I encounter any other value.

```
<div status='0'></div>
<div status='0'></div>
<div status='0'></div>
<div status='1'></div>
<div status='0'></div>
```

The following example I would only need the first 2 elements

```
<div status='0'></div>
<div status='0'></div>
<div status='1'></div>
<div status='1'></div>
<div status='0'></div>
```

Comment: What if the first div had status '1'? Would you want to select no elements at all, or find the first '0' and start there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var divs = [];
$('div[status]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('status') === '0') {
        divs.push(this);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Very elegant! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// Get the first div with status
var $first = $('div[status]').eq(0);
// value of first, so that it works with any status condition
// not just status="1"
var initial = $first.attr('status');
console.log(initial);

$first
  .nextUntil('div[status!='+ initial +']', 'div[status='+ initial +']')
  .andSelf().css('background', 'red');
```

The first arg for `nextUntill` is where to stop the selection, and the 2nd argument which elements to match.

**[Check  Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/bMwHH/1/)**

Comment: I like the `.nextUntil()` plan, but I suspect if the first div in the list happens to be status '1' then the OP will want to select no divs at all rather than skipping to start at the first '0'. (Have to wait for them to confirm, I guess.)

Answer (score 0):

First 3 divs, only with status=0

```
$('div:lt(3)[status=0]')
```